# Can tags be removed?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I was looking through the new tags and spotted "very" and "snowclone".

This made me wonder how tags are deleted, since I couldn't find a button anywhere.

Does one have to go to each question the tag is mentioned and remove it manually, or do moderators have the tools to do batch-removals?

Should one even be able to remove tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- tags can be removed, as Andrew noted, by removing all tags from each individual item that has it. An unintended consequence of attempting to do so is that a change in tag on a question is considered an edit, and any edit moves it to the top of the activity queue, so any en masse removal of an unliked tag would push off new questions and answers from the top of the high activity queue. For a tag attached to only a couple questions, that is ignorable. But for more than 5 or so, the new questions/answers would be almost pushed out of existence.
- as to those two particular tags

  - 'very' is a strange tag to have because it is about a single word. I don't know if ELU should have a subset that is essentially a dictionary. But for that particular question the word 'very' is searchable without the tag.
  - 'snowclone' is a new submission of mine. It is a viable linguistic term that should be useful here. That is hasn't been used before is mildly surprising to me only because I feel like there have been enough questions here on ELU with that theme.
- the tag editing system on ELU is, as much work as has been put into it, in need of augmentation. It might work for SO (differentiating questions by programming language), but here ... there just doesn't seem to be enough utility (in correspondence to the effort to edit).

Comment: I see, I didn't recognise snowclone as a valid term.

Comment: I edited to add a link (because it is not the most well-known of technical terms).

Comment: I suspect snowclone hasn't been introduced before because, as @AndrewLeach notes, it's usually not familiar to the people asking the question. Which means it will be most useful if other folks start applying it retroactively to questions, and probably useful more for the overall project of building a Q&A compendium of the English language than for getting appropriate answers for OPs or spotting interesting questions as they come in. I'd vote to keep it, as it's specific, meaningful, and unlikely to be grossly over-used.

Answer (score 4):

Tags can be removed, but the way to do that is to remove them from every question. Once a tag is no longer used, it doesn't exist. For a tag which has only been used once, that's not difficult. Just edit it out; editing without review does need 2k rep.

Tags can be blacklisted so they don't reappear, but for that to happen it's necessary* that it no longer exists in the first place.

The [one question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473466/very-afraid-or-very-much-afraid) to which [very](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/very) has been attached seems to be more about *much,* which is already covered by the [adverb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverb) tag. I've removed it.

I'm ambivalent about [snowclone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snowclone). It might be useful as a tag: normally questions generate an answer [using the word](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/snowclone) rather than the question already knowing what it's talking about.

---

<sub>*Well, I believe that special dispensation might be allowed for a common tag which has become meaningless, like [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar).</sub>